# How can I add an edge and align it with another edge?

Tags: edit-mode

I need to add another edge to my mesh and align it to a bottom edge (the top edge is not parallel to the bottom edge.

I have tried selecting the side edges and then subdivide but I cannot get the resulting edge to align with the bottom edge pressing either E or F (as I have done previously using loop cut). I have also tried loop cut which also won't align.

Refer to image below where I have added an edge (in yellow) which I cannot get aligned to the bottom edge. Note all existing edges were created via extrude and/or bevel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: GG then E to align with the adjacent edge, F to switch to the opposite, should work, but you could simply use the Knife:K to activate, A to cut orthogonally, C to cut through. Share your file so that we can test if necessary

Comment: Thanks moonboots.  Yes I now remember about GG but when I just tried that I still could not get the edge to align.   I have uploaded the blend file for your perusal.  Lastly I cannot understand knife cut even though I have experiemen5ted.

Comment: I've just tested your mesh, both GG and the knife tool work on the face on the right if this is where you're trying to cut

Comment: Thanks moonboots. While I could not get GG to work I just added the edge us8ing the knife K. It automatically allowed me to choose the other edge (side) with the cut parallel (aligned to) the bottom edge. Voila, it works.